# Select multiple markers with a mouse click drag box

Tags: javascript, google-maps-markers

I have many markers on my map. This causes problems when the markers are close together because it makes it difficult or impossible to click the specific one I want.

I was wondering if it was possible to drag the mouse to select and catch all the markers within the box.

Is this possible and, if so, could someone point me in the right direction to accomplish it?

Thank you!

Comment: There isn't a mouse-drag event on google maps unfortunately, but you could use the drawing library to make a shape and then check to see if [any markers are located inside](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/poly-containsLocation)